# Create Sets from a Set based on Time Differences

Tags: java, date, collections

let’s say I have a collection of `Logs` and I want to create different collections based on date ranges. For example, if the collection had 4 items.

```
logs[0].dateCreated = 12:00
logs[1].dateCreated = 12:10
logs[2].dateCreated = 12:50
logs[3].dateCreated = 12:60
```

I want items 0-1 in a Set and then put 2-3 in a Set. The criteria being within 30 seconds of one another. My psuedo code idea is:

```
logs.forEach(item -> { 
  // if on first item, just put it in the first collection
  // store this item as the initial time diff
  // if the next item is within 30 seconds, add to same colletion
  // otherwise, add  item to new collection, this item now becomes the time diff
  // rinse and repeat.
});
```

Wondering if there is a better/more efficient way.

Comment: Are those `12:xx` values representing a time-of-day or a span-of-time? As in, "mail arrived at 12:20" or "walking to the post office took 12 minutes and 20 seconds"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you really are tracking just a time-of-day, then use the `LocalTime` class for objects in your array/collection.

```
List<LocalTime> logTimes = new ArrayList<>();
logTimes.add( LocalTime.parse( "12:00" ) ) ;
logTimes.add( LocalTime.parse( "12:10" ) ) ;
logTimes.add( LocalTime.parse( "12:50" ) ) ;
logTimes.add( LocalTime.parse( "13:00" ) ) ;  // No such thing as `12:60`.
```

You seem to be mixing up time-of-day with a span-of-time. If you want the starting time, followed by a collection of spans over half-minute, you should track those separately.

Did you mean 30 minutes instead of 30 seconds?

Did you really mean a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) rather than a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)? A `Set` eliminates duplicates. If that is indeed what you want, just replace `List` with `Set` in this example code, along with `new HashSet` for `new ArrayList`.

```
LocalTime start = logTimes.get( 0 ); // Get first item. Uses annoying zero-based index counting.
LocalTime previous = start ;
List<LocalTime> sublistTimes = logTimes.subList( 1 , logTimes.size() ) ;  // A view over the original list, not actually separate.
List<Duration> spans = new ArrayList<>();
Duration limit = Duration.ofMinutes( 30 );
for( LocalTime t : sublistTimes ) {
    Duration d = Duration.between( previous , t ) ;
    if( d.compareTo( limit ) > 0 ) {  // If over the limit…
        System.out.println( "From " + previous + " to " + t + " = " + d ) ;
        spans.add( d ) ; // Remember the delta from previous time-of-day to this time-of-day because it is over our threshold.
    }
    previous = t ;  // Setup the next loop.
}

String results = "Start: " + start + " Deltas over limit of " + limit + ": " + spans ;
System.out.println( results ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/G1EI0p).

> From 12:10 to 12:50 = PT40M
>
> Start: 12:00
>
> Deltas over limit of PT30M: [PT40M]